# breezejs: mixing EF context and IQueryable

Tags: javascript, breeze

I'm facing an unusual situation here. I have a WebAPI breeze controller with the following action method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Client> Clients(bool IsEbasys = false)
    {
        if (IsEbasys)
        {
            List<Client> lst = new List<Client>();
            lst.Add(new Client() {  FirstName = "Sam", LastName = "Smyth" });
            return lst.ToList().AsQueryable<Client>();
        }
        else
        {
            return _contextProvider.Context.Clients;
        }
    }
```

2 scenarios:

If I remove the `[BreezeController]` attribute on my class, the hardcoded list will be returned fine. But of course the second one no longer works (actually it returns all the Client entities regardless of the query filters).

If I add the `[BreezeController]` attribute on my class, then querying the context works as expected, but for some reasons the hardcoded list is returned as en empty array to the client, although it should contain one client.

Is there a workaround to this  ? Or can't I just mix the two in the same controller ?

Comment: anyone knows if this could be done ?  So far I've had to create two separate controllers (one breeze controller and one 'regular' controller'), which is not ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to add the attribute BreezeQueryable to the method?

```
[HttpGet]
[BreezeQueryable]
public IQueryable<Client> Clients(bool IsEbasys = false)
{
    if (IsEbasys)
    {
        List<Client> lst = new List<Client>();
        lst.Add(new Client() {  FirstName = "Sam", LastName = "Smyth" });
        return lst.ToList().AsQueryable<Client>();
    }
    else
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Clients;
    }
}
```

From http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-api-controller

BreezeQueryableAttribute

Breeze clients query for data by sending HTTP GET requests to the controller formatted as OData Query URLs. For example, a client could query for active (non-archived) Todos, sorted by creation date, with this URL.

1
.../breeze/todos/Todos?$filter=IsArchived eq false&$orderby=CreatedAt
With the Breeze [Queryable] attribute [1] , Breeze can extend the IQueryable returned by the controller's Todos action method (see code sample above). The net effect is a LINQ query such as this one:

1
2
query = _contextProvider.Context.Todos
           .Where(t => t.IsArchived == false).OrderBy("CreatedAt");
Having revised the IQueryable, Breeze can execute it, invoking the query's LINQ provider (an Entity Framework provider in this example).

Comment: Not a problem. I learned that from a core dev a month or so ago.  There's a whole lot of interesting things you can do with that attribute. Make sure to check out WebAPI method overloads that include the ODataQueryOptions<T> as a param. Cool stuff. :D Happy codin'.